# Удаление объекта рядом с игроком в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в Unity3d можно удалить объект, находящийся рядом с игроком? Может, как-то через `Destroy();` с определенными параметрами? Ниже скрипт.

```
public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform player;
public Transform mushrums;
private Animator anim;

void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
public void HandUp () {

    float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
    Debug.Log(dist);
    if (dist <= 59)    
    {
        anim.Play("pick_up");
//здесь должен удаляться объект к которому подошел игрок
    }

}
}
```

Как сюда вставить функцию `OnTriggerEnter` не понимаю, unity на это ругается.
Мне посоветовали сделать так:

```
void Update() {
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(this.transform.position, 10);
int i = 0;
Transform nearest = null;
float nearDist = 9999;
while (i < hitColliders.Length) {
    float thisDist = (transform.position - hitColliders[i].transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
    if(thisDist < nearDist) {
        nearDist = thisDist;
        nearest = hitColliders[i].transform;
    }
}
if(nearest != null) {
    Destroy(nearest);
}
}
```

Но так все вешается видимо зацикливается.

Answer (score 1):

Уничтожать объект определенно надо через `Destroy();`, но чтобы определить что он находится рядом с игроком для этого лучше всего воспользоваться триггером. Для этого вешаете на объект `Collider` подходящий по форме, на нем выставляете признак что это триггер и пишете скрипт на обработку события

`void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }`

Чтобы триггер сработал на персонаже должен быть Rigidbody. И хорошо бы в методе проверять, что столкновение происходит с нужным объектом.
Вот видео-урок(https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers), он на английском, но в целом должно быть понятно что и как.

Comment: подправил вопрос

Comment: Вот смежная тема, там как раз обсуждается как использовать коллайдер (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480947/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83)

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все до ужаса просто.

В вашем коде, где написано `HandUp` (Кстати, подобрать по-английски будет **PickUp**)

Нужно просто написать `Destroy(mushrums.gameObject);`
где, судя из вашего класса `mushrums` - это `Transform` объекта. Следовательно, `mushrums.gameObject` это будет сам объект.

Другой код, который вы предоставили, где фигурируют `hitColliders` и то, о чем говорит @KingPeas  - это все удаляет, конечно, объект. Но не при клике на кнопку, а сразу, как только тот объект становится ближе указанной дистанции.

P.s. Тот второй код вешает всё потому, что в нем несколько неточностей и ошибок.
Одна из них: не хватает инкремента у счетчика `i++`. Без него, конечно же `i`, у которого значение `0` всегда будет меньше чем `hitColliders.Length`

Comment: так уже пробовал, но выдает ошибку Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true); и такой объект не один и я так полагаю удаляться все такие объекты, поэтому и нужен ближний объект

Comment: Ну судя из вашего кода, мой код должен отрабатывать...потому что в вашем коде фигурирует лишь один объект........ а ваша ошибка выходит из-за того, что вы пытаетесь удалить не объект, а исходный ассет. точнее  пытаешься удалить префаб из ассетов а не из сцены....вот ...Видно вы где-то делаете что-то типа: `someObj = Resources.Load("someResource") as GameObject;` а потом уже пытаетесь удалить это...... либо вы еще что-то там мудрите и получается у вас массив.....так что надо смотреть больше чем этот код.. что вы там делаете что получаете такую ошибку..... а с объектом код работает на отлично)

Comment: да попробовал с одним объектом все отлично, но у меня другая ситуация. Есть игрок и есть объекты которые нужно собирать, т.е. объект не один. Сюда `public Transform mushrums;` как вы и сказали засунут префаб

Comment: @МихаилЧ Этот самый префаб должен располагаться на сцене... точнее объект, который инстанциируется на сцене из него-  должен быть на сцене...и уже с ним надо манипулировать.. а вы, видимо, напрямую из ассетов префаб засунули..... вот и ошибка. в общем тут нужно во многом разбираться и смотреть много кода где и что вы делаете. но суть, почему ошибка - я описал. И то, что удаление делается так как описал - тож верно)

Comment: это понятно все, но как манипулировать сразу всеми объектами mushrums, если не добавлять этот префаб в скрипт. А кода здесь почти нет, есть объект на нем нет скриптов и есть персонаж на котором висит скрипт hand(самый верхний) и к которому обращается кнопка.

Comment: @МихаилЧ Ну как, если хотите сразу всеми манипулировать, надо все их добавить  в лист `List<Transform> targets;` и оперировать списком..... или чтоб подобрать гриб - в начале надо кликнуть непосредственно на тот гриб, и занести непосредственно конкретно его одного в переменную `Transform mashrum` для удаления. Но точно сказать в данной ситуации не видя всего что вы делаете в коде - нельзя

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34062/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 0):

Наконец-то нашел решение. Вот полный скрипт.

```
public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform player;
public Transform mushrums;
private Animator anim;
GameObject closest;
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
GameObject FindClosestEnemy() {
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("mushrums");
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance) {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
public void HandUp () {

    float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
    Debug.Log(dist);
    if (dist <= 59)
    {
        anim.Play("pick_up");
        Destroy(FindClosestEnemy());
    }
}
}
```