# Убийство врагов прыжком на голову

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Делаю по этому [туториалу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdGeGQPPW7E&index=12&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Up8XNvM3OSqgbJoMQgHkVz). Дошёл до урока уничтожения врагов прыжком на голову.

После выполнения пошаговых инструкций у меня не исчезали противники (на видео 18.20) (анимации смерти в виде партикл систем у меня нет,поэтому они должны просто исчезнуть после команды Дестрой).

Код:
EnemyHelthManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyHealthManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int enemyHeath;

    public GameObject deathEffect;

    public int pointsOnDeath;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (enemyHeath <= 0) 
        {
            //Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            ScoreManager.AddPoints(pointsOnDeath);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void giveDamage(int damageToGive)
    {
        enemyHeath -= damageToGive;
    }

}
```

HurtEnemyOnContact:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HurtEnemyOnContact : MonoBehaviour {

    public int damageToGive;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Enemy")
            other.GetComponent<EnemyHealthManager>().giveDamage(damageToGive);
    }
}
```

Также выскочила ошибка 'Неявное преобразование типа string в bool' в этом коде на моменте =>  if (other.tag == "Enemy").Хотя на видео, всё в порядке.

[Сам проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjap5nhsce7au1x/Lost%20Penguin%20v.0.0.8.5.rar?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я `Enemy` назвал слой(Layer),а не тег(Tag) в инспекторе.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню юньку и сам c#

```
if (other.tag.ToString() == "Enemy")
```

это насчет ошибки

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке исчезло,но теперь сам враг исчез.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer , враг исчез вообще или после прыжка? Если после прыжка, то у вас в коде и написано Destroy, а анимация - отключена.

Comment: @Monk вообще. Опять же напомню, что делаю (как мне кажется), всё согласно видео.Возможно ошибка может крыться и в Enemy Health Manager, создание которого описывается в предыдущих видео данного туториала.

Comment: @Monk Раскомментировал строчку Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation); - враг снова появился,но при прыжке на голову ничего не происходит. То есть мой персонаж просто сидит у врага на голове. Может у меня что-то не так с колайдерами? (если что к вопросу прикреплена ссылка на сам проект).

Comment: @ArtikSlayer банально - надо добавить врагу Тег `Enemy`, чтоб работало определение `other.tag == "Enemy"`.... Возможно и предыдущая ошибка `'Неявное преобразование типа string в bool'` тоже была из-за этого

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тег стоит. В проекте это можно увидеть на объекте *Enemy_Snail*.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer ........открыл сцену v.0.0.6, которая самая поздняя по дате... тега нет. поставил - работает. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Н-невнимательность. Как обычно. Спасибо за наводку.